# ListItem VB .net

Tags: vb.net, foreach, listitem

hi i have a problem to iterate/ read a listItem in asp.net... i'd to read this listItem

.....

```
Dim l As ListItem ' it's already load



Protected Sub load_menu(ByVal address_url As String)
    Dim slug As String = address_url.Substring(25) 

    Dim str As String
    For Each str In l 'HERE THERE IS A PROBLEM
        If String.Compare(str, slug) = 0 Then
            txt_url.Text = str
            Stop
        End If

    Next
End Sub
```

compiler tell me that there is a problem with L, because is not a collection...

Do you have ideas how iterate a ListItem?

thanks for Your time :)

Comment: From MSDN *A ListItem control represents an **individual** data item within a data-bound list control, such as a ListBox or a RadioButtonList control.* This element has no items you can iterate. Shouldn't you just get the value or text like this `ListIem.Text` or `ListItem.Value`?

Comment: I am not sure I have understood your issue. In case, here is the link to MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listitem.aspx :)